# Noobie question regarding calling my FUNC

Tags: python, appium

My question is how i call for my function and if and what I have done wrong here?, My intentions it to press a button using x and y but i don't want to hard code it. My previous way was to. This is appium

```
    actions = TouchAction(self.driver)
    actions.tap(x=357, y=1187)
    actions.perform()
```

But i do not want to hard code since this will be reused alot. So I have written.

```
all_xys_screen_size_large = {
    'hangUp': {'x': 357, 'y': 1187},
    '3Dots' : {'x': 670, 'y': 115},
}

def allXYS(self):

    actions = TouchAction(self.driver)
    actions.tap(self.all_xys_screen_size_large)
    actions.perform()
```

And when later trying to call the FUNC like this

```
self.allXYS(self.all_xys_screen_size_large['hangUp'])
```

I get a error message

self.allXYS(self.all_xys_screen_size_large['hangUp'])
TypeError: allXYS() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

---

Ran 1 test in 57.866s

FAILED (errors=1)

Comment: Yeah, you're trying to pass a dict to `allXYS`, but it does not seem like `allXYS` accepts any arguments (besides the implicit `self`)…

Comment: So how should i write it ? BR

Comment: Just `self.allXYS()`!? Passing an argument to it seems nonsensical; but then again we don't really know what you *want* to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your functions needs to accept the argument using a parameter.
2. You need to use that parameter to pass the value to `tap`.
3. You'll want to unpack the dict to keyword arguments.

```
def allXYS(self, xy):
    actions = TouchAction(self.driver)
    actions.tap(**xy)
    actions.perform()
```